# How many subsets of size 22 are there?

Tags: combinatorics

I am working on an assignment, and am stuck on this question.

> Suppose we have a set $S = \{1, 2, 3, \dots, n\}$ where $n \ge 22$. Let there be an integer $r$ where $n \ge r \ge 22$. How many subsets of set $S$ of size $22$ are there whose largest element is equal to $r$?

I would really appreciate any help on what to do to get started.

Comment: Did you mean $r = k$? Otherwise, how does $r$ come into play?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have that the largest element out of $22$ is equal to $r$, then we need $21$ numbers between $1$ and $r-1$. The answer is therefore $\binom{r-1}{21}$.

Also, you can ignore $n$, since it is always bigger than $r$.